# How to curve jagged edges of a matplotlib contourplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, smoothing, contourf

I am trying to produce a smooth contour plot from two irregular arrays which form the base grid

```
phiMdata = [0.4,0.5,0.6,0.62,0.64,0.66,0.68,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.72,0.74,0.76,0.78,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.82,0.84,0.86,0.88,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.86,0.88,0.9,0.92,0.94,0.96,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.92,0.94,0.96,0.98,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.94,0.96,0.98,1.0,1.02,1.04,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.02,1.04,1.06,1.08,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.02,1.04,1.06,1.08,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.04,1.06,1.08,1.1,1.12,1.14,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.06,1.08,1.1,1.12,1.14,1.16,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.12,1.14,1.16,1.18,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.12,1.14,1.16,1.18,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.12,1.14,1.16,1.18,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.12,1.14,1.16,1.18,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,
        0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.14,1.16,1.18,1.2,1.22,1.24,1.3,1.4,1.5]
```

and

```
phiQdata = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,
        2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,
        3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,
        4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,
        5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,
        6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,
        7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,7.0,
        8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,8.0,
        9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,
        10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,
        11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,11.0,
        12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,12.0,
        13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,13.0,
        14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,14.0,
        15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0],
```

and the z array which contains both values and NaNs. The z array is:

```
z= [0.2578, 0.16785, 0.0719, 0.04335, 0.03, 0.015, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, 0.2766, 0.212, 0.1075, 0.0821, 0.04209, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, 0.2986, 0.2626, 0.1903, 0.08574, 0.04, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, 0.2928, 0.2927, 0.259, 0.16496, 0.08, 0.04, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.297, 0.27397, 0.2119, 0.1090, 0.06110, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3111, 0.2902, 0.2454, 0.1679, 0.1153, 0.06532, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.321, 0.3112, 0.2663, 0.2060, 0.08, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3362, 0.319, 0.2812, 0.2319, 0.1356, 0.09246, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3379, 0.328, 0.2977, 0.2524, 0.1772, 0.1166, 0.09, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.339, 0.3297, 0.3017, 0.2677, 0.2060, 0.1318, 0.0756, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.343, 0.3375, 0.3065, 0.2795, 0.2281, 0.0921, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3483, 0.3385, 0.315, 0.2901, 0.2448, 0.1482, 0.1008, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3397, 0.3299, 0.2950, 0.2625, 0.1815, 0.1517, 0.1041, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3407, 0.333, 0.3014, 0.2704, 0.2054, 0.1832, 0.1527, 0.1029, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan,
np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, 0.3426, 0.333, 0.3120, 0.2818, 0.2247, 0.1829, 0.1514, 0.0967, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan, np.isnan]
```

The values and NaNs are separated by "crossover" lines which should have values going all the way up to the boundary. I first attempted to plot this using matplotlib's "triangulation" and contourf as such:

```
xi = np.linspace(0.4, 1.2, 1000)
yi = np.linspace(1.0, 15.0, 1000)
triang = tri.Triangulation(phiMdata,phiQdata)
interpolator = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang, z)
Xi, Yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
zi = interpolator(Xi, Yi)
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=15, cmap="terrain")
```

which produces something like this plot:
[image: Tri contour plot]

This is good but I want to smooth the contours a lot more to be more like curves, and also I want my plot to reach all the way to the black line on the right (there is data here so it should do). I then tried instead interpolating across the phiM values for each phiQ with interp1d, then putting all of this into interp2d and plotting using plt.pcolor. This produces this:
[image: Smoother plot]
which is smoother but suffers from problems at the left as I had to replace NaNs with zeros before interpolating, then add them back in. It also doesn't solve the jagged problem. Realistically I want something as smooth as the black curve on the right here.
[image: Desired Curve]

How do I go about this?

Comment: Replacing the `LinearTriInterpolator` with a cubic version `CubicTriInterpolator` would make the curves much smoother.  You might also experiment with replacing the z nans with -0.001 or so, and setting `levels=np.arange(0, 0.36, 0.025)` or something similar.  (Without the z-values it is hard to experiment.

Comment: Will try that now, many thanks! Have also just added the z array to be able to experiment.

Comment: Seems like ``CubicTriInterpolator`` has problems for some reason, masking large amounts of the data leaving it very patchy.

Comment: You probably need more data points. Couldn't you add datapoints from your curves as extra values for `phiMdata, phiQdata, z` ?  Also, you can let matplotlib take care of the triangulation via `plt.tricontourf`